# JS - ternary statement inside Object.keys()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

When I put a `ternary statement` or an `if statement` inside the Object.keys() like bellow:

```
 Object.keys(date).forEach((index) => {
        dates[date[index].id] !== undefined ?
          dates[date[index].id] =
          [...dates[dates[date[index].id], dates[date[index].name]
          : null;
      });
```

I get this error from the Linter:

```
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression. (no-unused-expressions)
```

When I use a regular if statement, I get this error,

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token (Fatal)
```

Why?

Comment: I don't just get an error from a linter, I get a *syntax error* from any JS parser as well. You clearly have misnested brackets.

Comment: `dates[date[index].id] !== undefined ? [...dates[dates[date[index].id], dates[date[index].name]: null;`

Comment: "*When I use a regular if statement*" - please post the code of that attempt

Comment: What is `date`?

Comment: Even with the missing `]` added it's almost completely illegible.

Comment: It is yelling since you use a ternary as an if..... bad practice.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've duplicated `dates` in and got some missing brackets in the assignment:

```
dates[date[index].id] = [...dates[dates[date[index].id], dates[date[index].name]
```

Which should be:

```
dates[date[index].id] = [..dates[date[index].id], dates[date[index].name]]
```

Demo:

```
Object.keys(date).forEach((index) => dates[date[index].id] !== undefined ?
        dates[date[index].id] = [...dates[date[index].id], dates[date[index].name]] : null);
```

Comment: Parentheses are not necessary surrounding assignment

Comment: @guest271314 - right you are. He was missing some brackets.

Comment: I think rather than missing brackets, he was unwittingly duplicating `dates[`. Remove it once from `dates[dates[date…`  and once from `dates[date…`.

Comment: @Bergi - indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular if condition, without a ternary expression, which the linter does not like.

```
Object.keys(date).forEach((index) => {
    if (dates[date[index].id] !== undefined) {
        dates[date[index].id] = [
            ...dates[dates[date[index].id]],
            dates[date[index].name]
        ];
    }
});
```

Basically the tenary is used with an assignment outside of the operator, like

```
x = a > 4 ? 7: 8;
```

whereas your assignment takes place inside of the operator.

Comment: When I use a regular if statement,  Parsing error: Unexpected token (Fatal)

Comment: You forgot about closing brackets. Change `dates[date[index].id] = [...dates[dates[date[index].id], dates[date[index].name];` to `dates[date[index].id] = [...dates[dates[date[index].id]], dates[date[index].name]];`

Answer (score 2):

You just have a few syntax errors in there, probably stemming from the overcomplicated nesting of property accesses. Keep it simple:

```
for (const index in date) {
    const id = date[index].id;
    if (dates[id] !== undefined) {
        dates[id].push(date[index].name);
        // or if you insist:
        // dates[id] = [...dates[id], date[index].name];
    }
}
```